# Striking through a number in an ordered list CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML ordered list, that I need to apply a strikethrough to. I have done this in CSS as below:

```
.Lower-Alpha {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
  margin-top: 2pt;
  margin-bottom: 2pt;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

The issue I am having is that this strikes through the content in the list, but not the number of the list (and I need to do both).

Eg I am getting:
a. <strike>struckthrough content</strike>

but I need:
<strike>a. struckthrough content</strike>

Any suggestions welcome.
Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

easy as pie: `list-style-position: inside;`

http://jsfiddle.net/seler/NWbrR/

edit: it looks like it's browser dependent behaviour. in mozilla it renders ok.

edit2:
for full browser compability u can use this js script: http://jsfiddle.net/seler/32ECB/

Comment: note: this will impact rendering if the list item is more than a line long, as it will wrap under the number, rather than wrapping to the indented position.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported in WebKit (Chrome 11)

Comment: @Chris Fulstow Its nicely working with Chromium, using WebKit version 534.24.

Comment: Thanks for the update Seler. I think I'm going to go with your first suggestion, but it's good to know how to do this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

@Haem; You can apply `:after` property

```
li:after{
    border-top:1px solid red;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    margin-top:-8px;
}
```

check the fiddle for more may be that's help you

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/NWbrR/4/

Answer (score 0):

the list style is NOT styleable in this way - you'd have to remove the list style identifier (a,b,c etc) inside the li as content.

Answer (score 0):

This is default browser behaviour and you wont be able to strike through the number/letter provided by the list.
If it is possible in your situation you could hide the numbering provided by the list and add it to the list text content yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to take care of the numbering yourself - either manually, server-side, or some jQuery - and use an unordered list like this:

```
<style>
.Lower-Alpha
{
  margin-top: 2pt;
  margin-bottom: 2pt;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  list-style: none;
}
</style>

<ul>
   <li class="Lower-Alpha">a. Foo</li>
   <li class="Lower-Alpha">b. Bar</li>
</ul>
```

This'll render as:

<strike>a. Foo</strike>

<strike>b. Bar</strike>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had thought of that, but was hoping there would be an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

1. Create a wrapper `<div>` around the `<ul>`.
2. Style the wrapper `<div>` with the strikethru (or whatever other font size/style you're wanting for the list item numbers)
3. Style the `<li>` elements back to your normal font settings.

The list item numbers will then pick up the font settings from the parent `<div>`, and will have the strike-thru, and the list content will be normal text.

Note, this will only work if you want all your list item numbers styled the same way. Your question implies that this is what you want, but if you only wanted to do strike-thru on specific list items then you'd need to use @seler's solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, (and sorry for the ambiguity). Yes, unfortunately I need to be able to have a variety of list-items, some which are struck through, and some which are not.

Comment: @HaemEternal - ah well, now worries. hopefully the technique will be useful to know about anyway, even if not for this particular time. :)

Comment: Definitely. Better to have too many solutions than too few. Thanks again.

Comment: @feeela - unsemantic yes, but it *is* a solution. And I disagree with the 'very' -- a `<div>` wrapper is hardly a semantic faux-pas, and is used in a lot of cases to solve many problems. In any case, you don't *have* to add a `<div>` wrapper for this to work; it helps keep the styling separate, but you could do the same thing with any existing parent element. And yes, the accepted answer is better, but note the comments on it; it may not work for everyone.

Answer (score -1):

You can't style the list item. It might look better this way?