# TextDecorations Error in C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi & thanks in advance,

New to the Visual C# and ASP route and trying to create a shopping list: add, removing (either all or one at a time), works but I've come undone with the text decoration depending on a check box.

I'm trying to add some text decorations to the checkboxlist items' text depending on condition, in this case, whether or not a check box is 'checked'.

Below is my code, however I'm getting an error where the TextDecorations has no definition.

According to MSDN it comes from the System.Windows namespace, which is defined at the top of my code.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my function which I am trying to get to run through all of the list items and if the checkbox is checked then strikethrough the text,

```
protected void Finished_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(ListItem li in TaskList.Items)
    {
        if(li.Selected)
        {
            li.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a WPF feature.  You need to use CSS.

Comment: Ah that would explain it - mildly out of my comfort zone. Will have a go at that, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define css styles as per [example](http://jsfiddle.net/seler/NWbrR/) and then set required class to the li-item

```
if(li.Selected)
{
    li.CssClass = "dupa";
}
```

More here [Striking through a number in an ordered list CSS/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057787/striking-through-a-number-in-an-ordered-list-css-html)